# Use RegExp in JS to replace any html tags which include only whitespaces inside of it with its whitespaces(in same amount)

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to use RegExp in JS to replace any html tags which only include whitespaces(`' '` or `&nbsp;`) inside of it with its html encoded equivalent `&nbsp;`.

For example:

Replace

```
'<strong> &nbsp; &nbsp; </strong>' => '&nbsp; &nbsp;'
```

Another example,

Replace:

```
'<strong>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</strong> => '&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;'
```

Comment: We can't read your post. Please review formatting.

Comment: possibly this is related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression like this:

```
str = str.replace(/<(\w+)>((?:&nbsp;|\s)+)<\/\1>/g, '$2');
```

Explanation:

```
<(\w+)>          matches the start tag and captures the name
(                group to capture the content
(?:&nbsp;|\s)+   matches &nbsp; or whitespace, one or more times
)                ends group
<\/\1>           matches the end tag with the name of the start tag
```

The match is replaced by `$2`, i.e. the value in the second group, i.e. the content inside the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have the string

```
var string = "<strong>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </strong> <strong>no</strong>";
```

To match the only the `spaces` and the `&nbsp;` you can use

```
var result = string.replace(/<[^>]+>((&nbsp;| )+)<\/[^>]+>/gm, "$1");
```

Let me explain, `<[^>]+>` matches any tag and `<\/[^>]+>` any end tag.
the `(&nbsp;| )+` matches an space or an   many times